# 'to-many key not allowed here' exception but why?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I am building a maps app with the following entities:

[image]

[image]

Coordinate to Map is to-one and Map to Coordinate is a to-many relationship.

And my code would be:

```
 fileprivate var fetchedResultsControllerForMapEntity: NSFetchedResultsController<Map> = {
// Create Fetch Request
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Map> = Map.fetchRequest()

// Configure Fetch Request
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"newRelationship == %@", "peachesfarm")

// Create Fetched Results Controller
let fetchedResultsControllerForMapEntity = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

return fetchedResultsControllerForMapEntity
}()

fileprivate var fetchedResultsControllerForCoordinateEntity: NSFetchedResultsController<Coordinate> = {
// Create Fetch Request
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Coordinate> = Coordinate.fetchRequest()

// Configure Fetch Request
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "latitude", ascending: true)]
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "longitude", ascending: true)]

// Create Fetched Results Controller
let fetchedResultsControllerForCoordinateEntity = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

return fetchedResultsControllerForCoordinateEntity
}()
```

I am basically trying to retrieve the coordinates of the map called "peachesfarm" ONLY. Why might I be getting this exception?

Comment: `newRelationship` is confusing and ambiguous, you should name the relationship `Map` -> `Coordinate` **coordinates** (indicates -> many) and the reverse relationship `Coordinate` -> `Map` **map** (indicates -> one ). Then create `NSManagedObject` subclasses and use the properties.

Comment: Okay, but what is the problem with my code/db?

Comment: To fetch all coordinates for a map with a given name you have to create a fetch request on "Coordinate" and a predicate "map.name == %@" (in your terms: "newRelationship.name = %@") and not the other way around.

Comment: You cannot use a predicate *relationship == name*. If you want to get all coordinates for `peachesfarm`, get the `Map` with name `peachesfarm` and read the coordinates via the relationship property.

Comment: Thank you @Martin R worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSPredicate(format:"newRelationship == %@", "peachesfarm")
```

gives an error because "newRelationship" is a to-many relationship, which
cannot be compared for equality.

To fetch all coordinates which are related to a map with a given name,
you have to use a fetch request for "Coordinate", not for "Map".
Then use the key path to the name of the related map. Using the
relationship names as suggested by @vadian above that would be

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Coordinate> = Coordinate.fetchRequest()
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "map.name == %@", "peachesFarm")
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
```

Even better, use the `#keyPath` directive, where the compiler checks
the property names so that errors are avoided:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "\(#keyPath(Coordinate.map.name)) == %@", "peachesFarm")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have a question: how can I make "peachesfarm" dynamic? For example, a variable that holds this information but is located outside of the above function?

Comment: @konyv12: You can replace the literal string by a string variable: `NSPredicate(format: "map.name == %@", mapName)`